# Как поймать динамический элемент через Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Я новичок в Python и Selenium, так что я столкнулся с трудностью.
На сайте есть динамическая строка с кнопкой, на кнопку нужно нажать. В HTML виде она из себя представляет следующее:

```
<div id="start-serf-53183 (ТУТ МОЖЕТ БЫТЬ ЛЮБАЯ ЦИФРА, не только 53183)">
<a onclick="if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; funcjs['go-serf']('53183','30f11a58e383aec318139b8d095ccba9');return false;" title="ТУТ МОЖЕТ БЫТЬ ЛЮБАЯ ССЫЛКА" style="cursor:pointer;">ТУТ МОЖЕТ БЫТЬ ЛЮБОЙ ТЕКСТ</a><br>
<span class="serf-text">ТУТ МОЖЕТ БЫТЬ ЛЮБОЙ ТЕКСТ</span>
</div>
```

Я не вижу за что тут можно зацепится для Selenium, так как обычным xPATH не выйдет в виду динамического элемента.
Я пробовал так:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[@onclick^='if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers)']").click()
```

И так:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[1]/a").click()
```

И много иных вариантов. Увы, у меня не получается.
Помогите пожалуйста "поймать" динамичный элемент и кликнуть на него.

Comment: Можно ссылку на сайт? Или фрейм который там используется

Comment: Не надо добавлять метки в название вопроса )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя же там id есть, попробуй через него привязаться:

(By.ID,"start-serf-53183 (ТУТ МОЖЕТ БЫТЬ ЛЮБАЯ ЦИФРА, не только 53183)")

или так:
(By.XPATH,".//div[@id='start-serf-53183 (ТУТ МОЖЕТ БЫТЬ ЛЮБАЯ ЦИФРА, не только 53183)']/a")

Comment: Так-то круто, благодарю за ответ, я тоже думал про ID, но увы, нет.  Так как ID "start-serf-53183" может менять рандомно цифры. 
Это может быть и "start-serf-53183" и "start-serf-69545", и так далее...

Если конечно есть способ как указать ID-шник без цифор этих, то буду крайне благодарен, ибо я не придумал)

Comment: О боже! Я только что понял что это твой комментарий!)
Ну ок. если попробовать так:
(By.XPATH,".//div[contains(@id,'start-serf-')]/a")

Comment: огромное спасибо за ответ! 
Ваше решение о написание кода как "(By.XPATH,".//div[contains(@id,'start-serf-')]/a") " работает!
Благодарю!

Comment: Рад что помог!Спасибо и вам за галочку!)